# Difference of dynamic routing in Nextjs

Tags: next.js, url-routing

What is the difference among `[id].js`, `[...id].js` and `[[...id]].js` dynamic routing in Nextjs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Case:** `posts/[id].js`

When you are calling /posts/1099 - your page will be triggered (value of `id` variable is `1099`.

*Example:*

`/posts` - the system will trigger an error (id is not defined) or possible issue depending on your code.

`/posts/1099` - OK

`/posts/1011/info` - the system will trigger 404.

**Case**: `posts/[...id].js`

When you are calling /posts/1099 your page will be triggered (value of `id` variable is `1099`. If you call /posts/1011/info - the system will run your code with no error. (catching all paths by adding three dots), more info in [nextjs documentation.](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes)

`/posts` - the system will trigger an error (id is not defined) or possible issue depending on your code.

`/posts/1099` - OK

`/posts/1011/info` - OK (for all "nested routes", for example posts/a/b/c/d/e etc.).

**Case**: `posts/[[...id]].js`

Same as [...id].js but root path is included. ([nextjs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes))

`/posts` - OK.

`/posts/1099` - OK

`/posts/1011/info` - OK.