# how to handle nested level dynamic routing in Nextjs

Tags: next.js, routes

I have to implement 3 dynamic page routes in nextjs App.

1. /blog/category/postname
2. /blog/category
3. /blog/postname

I can implement 1 & 2 routes as dynamic routes but the problem is with the 3rd one. Actually, I need 3rd one because the production site is having the same slug for some of the posts. so want to maintain the same slugs in my nextjs application as well. Is there any solution to implement this??

Answer (score 0):

You have an [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/catch-all-routes) here.

In your `/pages`:

1. You create `blog` folder.
2. Case 1 (excluding root): In blog, you create `[...slug].js` (or `.tsx`)

   Example: `/blog` - ERROR ;`/blog/category` - OK; `/category/postname` - OK
3. Case 2 (lot of levels, including root): In blog, you create `[[...slug]].js` (or `.tsx`)

   Example: `/blog` - OK;`/blog/category` - OK; `/category/postname` - OK
4. You handle all logic inside this file.

You can [check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72938170/difference-of-dynamic-routing-in-nextjs/72938622#72938622) to understand how routing is done.